# Create circle around a letter in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I was trying to create a circle around a letter here is my code, but it was not creating a perfect circle

```
         Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 2)),
            child: InkWell(
              child: Text(
                "A",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 15),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

[image]

I've also tried with *height and width* of the *Container* then some portion of letter is hidden.

```dart
          Container(
            height: 30,
            width: 30,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 2)),
            child: InkWell(
              child: Text(
                "A",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 15),
              ),
            ),
          )
```

[image]

But if I use **Icon Widget** instead of text widget it was creating perfect circle,

```dart
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 2)),
            child: InkWell(
              child: Icon(
                Icons.add,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Containers, you can use the `shape` property to give it a circular shape.

It would be something like this :

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration (
     shape: BoxShape.circle,
  ),
child: ....
)
```

Answer (score 12):

Use this:

```
 CircleAvatar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      child: Text("A"),
  );
```

You can also make use of the many other flags in `CircleAvatar`, like `maxRadius` or `foregroundImage`, like this:

```
 CircleAvatar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      child: Text("A"),
      maxRadius: 30,
      foregroundImage: NetworkImage("enterImageUrl"),
  );
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If I face multiple widget I prefer by creating a widget and wrapping others.

**Container `BoxShape.circle,` depends on height**

```
class WrapWithCircle extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  late final EdgeInsets edgeInsets;
  late final Color color;
  WrapWithCircle({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
    this.edgeInsets = const EdgeInsets.all(8),
    this.color = Colors.white,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      padding: edgeInsets,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        border: Border.all(
          width: 2,
          color: color,
        ),
      ),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```